# Algorithms with O(sqrt(N)) SPACE complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics, space-complexity

Are there any known algorithms for formulated problems that require a SPACE complexity of O(sqrt(N))? I know that algorithms with that big-O time complexity exist.

Comment: For an important problem called 3sum, there is the following trade-off. If you want $O(n^2)$ time, the best-known space complexity is $O(\sqrt{n})$. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07285

Answer (score 15):

$\sqrt{n}$ space is somewhat unusual; the most likely reason for such a complexity to emerge is as a result of a so-called *meet in the middle* scheme.

Two notable examples off the top of my head are the classical *sieve of Eratosthenes* and the *baby-step giant-step* algorithm for the discrete logarithm over a finite group.